# Why isn't my app/apk being saved onto testing android device?

Tags: android

When I test/debug my app in android studio on my emulator or physical device it's never saved onto the device. It launches the activity but when it's closed the icon is nowhere to be found. Please help.

Mainifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.twittershare"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
    <!-- Permission - Internet Connect -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- Network State Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/theuntitled"
    android:label="MyApp"
    android:theme="@style/Base.V22.Theme.AppCompat.Light"
    >
<activity
    android:name="com.betaprogrammer.config.newroad.MainActivity"
    android:label="MyApp"
    >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    <data
       android:host="t4jsample"
       android:scheme="oauth" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
    android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
<!-- Permission - Internet Connect -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<!-- Network State Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: that's doubtful. you can try to run your app from the device shell to see that it is still here.

Comment: Could you please share your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: You can't combine the intent-filter values for launcher and deep links. Keep those in separate intent-filter tags, like my answer shows.

Comment: This worked! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear! Please accept my answer so others can know the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`, do you have `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` in the `intent-filter` for your main Activity?

This should be inside the `<activity>` tags of your main Activity:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Without this tag, the launcher won't list your application.

EDIT: After seeing your manifest, you've combined your launcher and deep link `intent-filter` into one which will not work. You should keep them separate:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
        android:host="t4jsample"
        android:scheme="oauth" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to `/{PROJECT_NAME}/app/build/outputs/apk` and you can manually install it onto the device. Although in my experience the app has always installed onto the device when I run it.